# Retry Test Cases without TestNG

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, appium, webdriver-io

I'm completely stumped.

So I want to retry any test cases that have failed but I cant use `TestNG` because all of our tests are written in `JavaScript` so I can't use the `RetryAnalyzer`. `WebdriverIO` has `this.retries` but it doesn't work for retrying entire test cases, only test suites. Is there any other way I can do this?

I'm using `Appium` with `MochaJS`, `WebdriverIO`, and `Selenium` to test an Android.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you have already checked it but if not please check http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/retry.html

Thanks, Naveen

PS: I dont want to post this as answer. I want to comment this on your question but i do not have enough reputation.

Comment: Yeah I have but it didn't work for me. It kept giving me false positives and it would only work in test suites but not the entire test case